# ggplot over list of dataframes

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Example data

```
df_1 <- data.frame(a1 = abs(rnorm(50, 1, 1)),
                   b1 = rnorm(50, 1, 1))  
df_2 <- data.frame(a1 = rnorm(50, 1, 10),
                   b1 = rnorm(50, 1, 1))
df_3 <- data.frame(a1 = rnorm(50, 1, 10),
                   b1 = rnorm(50, 1, 1))

df_all <- list (df_1, df_2, df_3)
```

I use ggplot like this
and I get a satisfactory effect

```
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = df_all[[1]], aes(x = a1, y = b1), color = "blue", size = 0.05) +
  geom_line(data = df_all[[2]], aes(x = a1, y = b1), color = "blue", size = 0.05) + 
  geom_line(data = df_all[[3]], aes(x = a1, y = b1), color = "blue", size = 0.05)
```

The number of data frames changes every day, so a better solution is needed.
I thought of this solution (of course it is not correct)

```
lapply(df_all, ggplot()+ 
         function(x) (geom_line(x, aes(x=a1, y=b1), color='blue'))
       )
```

I don't want to convert the list to one frame

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to convert the list to one frame? Do you just mean you want there to be three separate lines? The idiomatic way to achieve this would be with one data frame e.g. `ggplot(dplyr::bind_rows(df_all, .id = "id"), aes(x = a1, y = b1, group = id)) + geom_line(color = "blue", size = 0.05)`. The effect can be achieved in other ways but it's useful to know what the constraints are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fortunately, `ggplot` can add lists of geoms:

```r
ggplot() +
  lapply(df_all, function(dat) geom_line(data=dat, aes(a1, b1), color="blue", size=0.05))
```

To demonstrate, I'll do this slightly differently by changing the colors:

```
ggplot() +
  Map(df_all, c("blue","darkgreen","red"),
      f = function(dat,col) geom_line(data=dat, aes(a1, b1), color=col))
```

(Slightly thicker and varying colors, for demo here.)

[image]

Though frankly, I think it's generally better to combine them and have a single frame, using ggplot's native `aes`thetic mapping for colors (even if you eschew the legend).

```r
ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(a1, b1, group = id, color = id),
            data = dplyr::bind_rows(df_all, .id = "id")) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c("1"="blue", "2"="darkgreen", "3"="red")
  )
```

[image]

I've taken the liberty of adding `color=id` to the aesthetics, again just to show that the separate lines are there. (The `group=id` needs to stay, though.)

The `bind_rows` is not required if you aren't using `dplyr`, we can also use `data.table::rbindlist(.., idcol="id")`. Base R requires a little more work to get the ID column in there, though it's far from prohibitive.

The one thing that this method requires, though, is that the aesthetic variables are the same name, so `a1` and `b1` need to be the same in all of the frames. (If not, it might be easy enough to rename them as you combine them ...)

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to loop over each data frame in `df_all`.

```r
g <- ggplot()

for (df_i in df_all) {
  g <- g + 
    geom_line(
        data = df_i,
        aes(x = a1, y = b1),
        color = "blue",
        size = 0.05
    )
}

g # to display the graph
```

If you wanted, for instance, the color change for each data frame in `df_all`, you can loop over an integer and call each element:

```r
g1 <- ggplot()

colors = c("red","blue","green")

for (i in 1:length(df_all)) {
  g1 <- g1 + 
    geom_line(
        data = df_all[[i]],
        aes(x = a1, y = b1),
        color = colors[[i]], 
        size = 0.05
    )
}

g1 # to display the graph
```

Comment: This is a good and simple approach. Since the OP brought up a variable number of frames in `df_all`, I often guard against "nothing" in it. For that, `1:length(df_all)` is going to fail, since `1:0` produces a length-2 vector `c(1, 0)` instead of not iterating like one might expect. I suggest `for (i in seq_along(df_all))` as an alternative.